# ng-repeat stuck in infinite loop angularfire 8.2

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'd like to figure out why this ng-repeat statement runs infinite.
Item.members has a length of 2 and contains userIds = true

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="items_renderer.html">
     <label>
       <span class="team-description" ng-show="!item.editing">{{item.name}}</span>

       <label ng-repeat="memberId in item.members">
         <span>{{ getMember(memberId) }}</span>
       </label>
     </label>
</script>


 <div ui-tree="options" class="teamlist">
     <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="teams" class="panel-teams">
         <li ui-tree-node ui-tree-handle
          ng-repeat="item in teams"
          ng-include="'items_renderer.html'">
         </li>
     </ol>
 </div>

$scope.getMember = (memberId) ->
  memberobj = fbutil.syncObject('users/' + memberId)
  memberobj.$loaded().then (ref) ->
    $scope.teamUser.push ref.name
    console.log $scope.teamUser
    return $scope.teamUser
```

It will just keep running indefinite.

["Sven Woldt", "Sven Woldt", "Sven Woldt", "Sven Woldt", "Sven Woldt", "Sven Woldt", "Sven Woldt", "Sven Woldt", "Sven Woldt", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Sven Woldt", "Yahoo", "Sven Woldt", "Yahoo", "Sven Woldt", "Yahoo",…]

So how could I restrict this to only return ["Sven Woldt", "Yahoo"]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is indefinite because you keep pushing to `$scope.teamUser` in your `$scope.getMember`

Answer (score 1):

It is indefinite because you keep pushing to `$scope.teamUser` in your `$scope.getMember` function. If you simply want to display name, why not try

```
$scope.getMember = (memberId) ->
  memberobj = fbutil.syncObject('users/' + memberId)
  memberobj.$loaded().then (ref) ->
    return ref.name
```

Comment: Hey kubuntu,thanks for your thoughts. I tried it this way as well and the same thing it runs indefinite. Does it make a difference that I have a nested ng-repeat. Like the memberId in item.members is inside the ng-repeat="item in teams".

Comment: I don't see `ng-repeat="item in teams"` in the question. One would understand better if you make the question complete.

Comment: Yes you are right, I apologize for that and adjusted the question.

Comment: Well, I am surprised that it didn't solve the problem. The nested `ng-repeat` should not be a problem. It should repeat for as many items in `teams`.

Comment: Yes I am suprised as well and indeed the nested ng-repeat has nothing to do with it. I tried it in a single repeat statement and the same issue. I assume that firebase's syncronization process is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

Every time Angular renders this `<span>{{ getMember(memberId) }}</span>` you end up (re)loading that member from Firebase, which in turn triggers a re-render.

Your flow is like this:

1. Angular starts to render your view
2. Angular calls `getMember`
3. `getMember` starts loading the data from Firebase
4. **At some point** the data is loaded and your `then` is executed
5. You push a new object onto the `$scope`, which in turn
6. Tells Angular to re-render your view, so we go back to step 1

Your `getMember` code should check if it has already loaded this member before. If it did, it shouldn't try to reload it - or at least not push it into the `$scope` again.

Comment: and what might be the best strategy for lets say you have certain users in a team of your users collection. You save them in team -> useruid: true. Now you wanna lookup those user details from your users collection and list them in the view. I implemented your suggested check but it still initializes like at least two times. Thanks for your answer frank :-)