# Trying to $watch a value returned by a function in the arrayFactory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a todo list that keeps track of how many tasks are completed. I am trying to extend a factory to add a sum() function. Here's a link to the docs that explains exactly what I am trying to do: 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-factories-firebasearrayextendfactory

I can get it generally working but I have to refresh the page in order to get it to update the sum() value. If I do a regular $watch then it crashes the browser and causes a world of pain. How can I get that sum() value to update every time I complete a task?

Working Solutions:

```
function tallyUp(){
      var tallllyProfiles = $firebase(new Firebase('https://demo.firebaseio.com/teams/' + team + '/profiles/')).$asObject();
      tallllyProfiles.$loaded().then(function(data) {
         angular.forEach(tallllyProfiles, function(value, key, tallllyProfile) {
            var user = value.uid;
            var ref = new Firebase('https://demo.firebaseio.com/teams/' + team + '/profiles/' + user + '/todo/');
            $scope.list = $firebase(ref, {arrayFactory: "TallllyFactory"}).$asArray();
            $scope.list.$loaded().then(function(data){
              value.tallyCount = data.sum();
              tallllyProfile.$save();
            });
          });
      });
    }

    tallyUp();

    $scope.$watch('activity', function(){
      console.log('this ran');
      tallyUp();
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: "it crashes the browser and causes a world of pain" error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no error message but $watching $scope.todoList and running the controller code creates an infinite loop where the getTallly service constantly runs.

Comment: In general you should not bind elements in your view to methods that trigger loading data from Firebase. This will indeed cause infinite loops if not controlled carefully. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27016649/209103

Comment: Instead you should load the data in your Controller and bind the data to the scope when it becomes available. This will trigger an update of the UI, but that will be all.